# How to jquery validate dynamically generated hidden textarea

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate multiple array of textarea which are added dynamically and are hidden as well. So what I am doing exactly is, I am using contenteditable div and whenever user inputs it sets the value of textarea which is hidden. So I am using validation for the textarea

I researched and found out about `.each` function and used it. But still it didn't work.

```
<div class="input-group">  
<textarea name="quiz[ques][0][ques]" style="display:none;" class="content-hidden">asd</textarea>            
<div contenteditable="true" id="question-edit-1" placeholder="Enter Question 1" name="quiz[question][]" class="content-visible valid" aria-invalid="false"></div>   
</div>

<div class="input-group">  
<textarea name="quiz[ques][1][ques]" style="display:none;" class="content-hidden">asd</textarea>            
<div contenteditable="true" id="question-edit-2" placeholder="Enter Question 2" name="quiz[question][]" class="content-visible valid" aria-invalid="false"></div>     
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
var ques = $('name^="quiz[ques]"');
ques.each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
             required: "Please enter the questioon"
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: make sure you are adding the *required* attribute set as true while appending any textarea & set as false while removing

Comment: But for jquery validation, I don't need to do that. Right ?

Comment: I tried, still it didn't work

Comment: try this `$('input[name="myname"]').rules('add', {...});`

Comment: You can use the class name instead of textarea name. Add a class into required textarea. i think this is issue occurs due to array name

Comment: or intead *name = quiz[ques][1][ques]* you can use *name='quiz[ques][]* and after that you can check with *var ques = $("textarea[name='quiz[ques][]']");*

Comment: @DanishAli, actually it is a textarea not input

Comment: Try to validate based on class name

Comment: I tried using class name, still it didn't work :/

Comment: try $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' }); not inside $(document).ready .
normally hidden fields are ignored for jquery validation.

Comment: @Sekhu, yes, hidden fields are ignored, however you can still add/remove rules from hidden fields and they will be validated when they are shown.  Secondly, putting `ignore` option inside `.setDefaults()` or `.validate()` has absolutely nothing to do with a `document.ready` handler function.  Please do not add to confusion here if you are unsure about something.  @DanishAli, please stop guessing when you are unsure about what is happening.

Comment: Regarding the [very first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449410/how-to-jquery-validate-dynamically-generated-hidden-textarea/55459148#comment97613197_55449410) by @Gulshan, topper1309 is correct, no need to worry about the HTML5 `required` validation attribute since the rules are being declared elsewhere.  So many blind guesses on this page, and nobody noticed the broken attribute selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code...

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var ques = $('name^="quiz[ques]"');
    ques.each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            ....
        });
    });
});
```

You are not supposed to add rules when you submit the form, otherwise, you cannot expect to validate fields before the submit button is clicked.  You would add rules *when you dynamically create* the new fields that need the rules.  So remove the `.rules()` method from the submit handler and put in inside whatever function creates these new fields.

*Dynamically create the new field(s) -> then immediately add the rule(s)*

---

Secondly, [your selector is totally broken](https://jsfiddle.net/61Lsrcfx/4/).  You are missing the outside brackets.  [Correct format for an "attribute starts with" selector is `$('[attribute="value"]')`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

So `name` attribute starts with `quiz[ques]` [would look like this](https://jsfiddle.net/61Lsrcfx/5/)...

```
$('[name^="quiz[ques]"]')
```

If you need to be more specific with the selector, you could add the `textarea` element...

```
$('textarea[name^="quiz[ques]"]')
```

---

Finally, by default, all hidden fields are ignored (not validated).  It's unclear why you would need to validate `textarea` elements if they remain hidden because the user could never interact with them.  You can add/remove rules from hidden fields and they will automatically validate when shown and not validate when hidden.

If you need to validate any fields that remain hidden, you will ned to override the default `ignore` settings.  `[]` means "nothing".  So `ignore: []` means ignore nothing (validate everything).

```
$('#myform').validate({
    ignore: [], // ignore nothing - validate everything
    // other settings....
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I got my solution in a perfect way